# Web API post object null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

---

A quick update,  So it turns out somewhere during my troubleshooting process this started working if I do the post from my application, but if I take the exact same data and try to post it via fiddler the oject is null.   It was so much "easier" to try after changes in fiddler that I stuck to it but it looks like it burned me and wasted hours.  I also tried posting this data via chromes rest client and it doesnt work.  I wish I knew why because if I cant get this to work via fiddler or chrome its really going to increase my troublshooting time in the future.

Thank you for trying to help.

---

I am trying to post data from a winforms app to Web API.  I had this problem initially but setting content type to application/json fixed it but now I am having the same behavior. I dont remember changing anything but I must have.  This occurs even when I post the data from fiddler. I removed everything from my viemodel but 1 string key value to try to eliminate format issues in the data itself but at the controller side the viewmodel is still null.  Not the values but the viewmodel itself. The controller is being reached but like I said the object is null

The controller looks like this

`[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage LogValidation([FromBody]ValidationViewModel validationviewmodel)
{
//Do something
}`

The Model

`public class ValidationViewModel
    {
        public string AssetName { get; set; }
}`

The data being posted

`{
\"AssetName\":\"testname\"
}`

In the interest of providing as much info as possible when I do the post from the client I am doing the following.  This is also how I generated the test data to use in fiddler

```
`public Task SubmitValidation()
{
ReportValidaton reportvalidation = new ReportValidaton();
var serializedReportValidation = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reportvalidation);          
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("MyURI");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeader("application/json"));
MediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
HttpContent content = new ObjectContent<ReportValidaton>(reportvalidation, jsonFormatter);
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("api/LogValidation/", content).Result;

}`
```

Comment: Did you try to POST { `AssetName:\"testname\"` }, can you see if a `GET` request works ?

Comment: I hadnt previously but after your comment I did and same result.  Thanks.  I am not sure what happened.  This worked last thursday.  Even tried with some test data that I generated last thursday to make sure I was using the same format and still no go.  I had some other data types in there as well but stripped them all out just to make sure it wasnt a data or formatting issue. Although I suspect this is on the right track,  there is some sort of formatting issue, I am just not seeing it.

Comment: Have you recently renamed your parameter? Often when this happens to me, it means I forgot to update my route mapping after a refactoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When posting from fiddler, ensure:

- that the `Content-Type` header is set to `application/json`
- that the data doesn't contain escaped strings: `{"AssetName":"testname"}` and NOT `{\"AssetName\":\"testname\"}`
- that the method is set to POST

Comment: This resolved the fiddler issue.  Thanks.  I was pulling the data from serializedReportValidation and should have been pulling it from content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;  Still not sure why posting from the client wasnt working but its working now so I am all good.

Comment: You mean posting from client _was_ working or _not_? Your question says client worked, fiddler din't.

Comment: If you mean Chrome clients (POSTMan or Advanced REST Client or similar), then the above steps should fix them too.

Comment: By client I was referring to a winforms app I developed. Should have clarified client did not mean fiddler or chrome.  When I first stated working on the issue neither the winforms app or fiddler would work so I assumed it was something on the service side.  From that point I started troubleshooting using only fiddler and chrome.  Something I changed corrected the issue on the service side but because I was using incorrectly formatted data I wasnt aware that I had corrected the issue at some other point.  Once I stripped out the \ everything worked,  the winforms app, chrome and fiddler.

Comment: So for the record, the code I posted above works.  It was just bad data